# Rails : Check authentication when json request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, authentication, devise

I am new to `Ruby on Rails`

In my project, I request to get `JSON` and `HTML` format on `index`. But I want to check `authentication` for `HTML` request only not `JSON` request.

I used `devise` gem, for `authentication`.

on my `Controller` I set

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only[:index], if: -> { request.format.json? }

def index
  @products = Product.all
  respond_to do |format|

    format.html 
    format.json { render :json => @products }
  end
end
```

Currently `JSON` and `HTML` request doesn't ask for `authentication`

How do I achieve this?

Is there any way to check `authentication` on `format.html { ... }`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, if: :skip_authenticate_user

  def index 
    ...
  end

  protected
    def skip_authenticate_user
      action_name=='index'  && (request.format.json? || request.format.xml?)
    end
```